# Connection refused while creating connection pool for postgresql vendor in glassfish server admin console

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, glassfish, connection-pooling

I am trying to create a connection pool to a PostgreSQL database in Glassfish server.
What I have done the steps as:

1. I copied the jar of postgresql jdbc jar in full path
   `C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext`
2. I have specified full path to the jar in the glassfish server admin console:

   **Pool Name:** post-gre-sql_CommonPush_postgresPool

   **Resource Type:** javax.sql.XADataSource

   **Datasource Classname:** org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource

In case of additional properties I have specified as:

```
driverClass:org.postgresql.Driver

URL: jdbc:postgresql://10.137.243.1:5432/CommonPush
portNumber: 5432
databaseName: CommonPush
serverName: 10.137.243.1(My system's IP)
user: postgres
password:
```

When I ping the above settings I get the error as:

> An error has occurred
>
> Ping Connection Pool for post-gre-sql_CommonPush_postgresPool is
>   Failed. Ping failed Exception - Connection could not be allocated
>   because: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are
>   correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
>   Please check the server.log for more details.
>
> Ping failed Exception - Connection could not be allocated because:
>   Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and
>   that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. Please check the
>   server.log for more details.

I am not able to figure out this problem, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Resource Type `javax.sql.DataSource`. I'm not sure if this is causing the error, you may also try to change the hostname to localhost.

Can you access the PostgreSQL DB via pgAdmin or psql commands?

Comment: Even I did change the resource type to javax.sql.DataSource the same error is occuring and I am able to access PostgreSQL through pgadmin

Comment: Are there any additional errors or information in your server.log?

Comment: RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE. endpoint = 'http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json'; attrs = '{id=post-gre-sql_CommonPush_postgresPool}'  in server log

Answer (score 0):

Cause could be that the user may not be having enough privileges on the db objects.
Grant the required privileges to the user, like:

```
###GRANT USAGE ON service_schema TO admin
sudo -u postgres psql -p 5432 -d service_db -c "GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA "service_schema" TO "admin";"
###GRANT PREVILEGES ON TABLES OF service_schema TO admin
sudo -u postgres psql -p 5432 -d service_db -c "GRANT ALL ON TABLES IN SCHEMA "service_schema" TO "admin";"
###GRANT PREVILEGES ON SEQUENCES OF service_schema TO admin
sudo -u postgres psql -p 5432 -d service_db -c "GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA "service_schema" TO "admin";"
###GRANT PREVILEGES ON FUNCTIONS OF service_schema TO admin
sudo -u postgres psql -p 5432 -d service_db -c "GRANT ALL ON FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA "service_schema" TO "admin";"
```